# asp.net 5 cannot find rc2 nuget packages

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have a simple asp.net 5 web application.
My project.json file contains dependency:

```
  "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens": "5.0.0-rc2-301060021"
```

When I restore nuget packages, this package is restored well on my machine. project.json file is in source control, but it does not work on other machine. It says that this package is not found.

Anyway, in nuget configuration Im pointing to my local nuget packages repository, which does not even contain asp.net 5 nuget packages. Where all of these packages come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RC2 has not yet been made public, we're still on RC1. Here is the [roadmap schedule](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap#schedule), which indicates sometime this year. If you do somehow have the package on your machine, you could setup another NuGet feed that others on your project could point to -- then simply place the package in there, so it's on shared feed.

[Here](https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) is some helping documentation that shows you how to do that.